# Issue integrating Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I want to use Firebase Cloud Functions in my APP. So for that I have installed ["node-v6.17.1.pkg"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/)  from official site.

After installing I run **"npm install -g firebase-tools"** that brought permission error SO I run **"sudo npm install -g firebase-tools"** and it may be successfully installed.

**Output like**

> /Users/ipatel/.npm-global/bin/firebase -> /Users/ipatel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
>
> @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-beta.5 postinstall /Users/ipatel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator
> node scripts/upgrade-warning

If you're using the Emulator via the Firebase CLI, you can
disregard this message.

If you're upgrading @google-cloud/functions-emulator, these
are the recommended upgrade steps:

1. Stop the currently running emulator, if any:

   ```
   functions stop
   ```
2. Uninstall the current emulator, if any:

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```
3. Install the new version of the emulator:

   ```
   npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```

If you have trouble after upgrading, try deleting the config
directory found in:

```
~/.config/configstore/@google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

Then restart the emulator. You can also check for any renegade
Node.js emulator processes that may need to be killed:

```
ps aux | grep node

/Users/ipatel/.npm-global/lib
└─┬ firebase-tools@6.6.0 
  ├─┬ @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-beta.5 
  │ ├─┬ @google-cloud/storage@1.7.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ @google-cloud/common@0.17.0 
  │ │ │ ├── array-uniq@1.0.3 
  │ │ │ ├── ent@2.2.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ google-auto-auth@0.10.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ gcp-metadata@0.6.3 
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ axios@0.18.0 
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── follow-redirects@1.7.0 
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.6 
  │ │ │ │ │ └── retry-axios@0.3.2 
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ google-auth-library@1.6.1 
  │ │ │ │   └─┬ gtoken@2.3.3 
  │ │ │ │     ├─┬ gaxios@1.8.3 
  │ │ │ │     │ ├─┬ abort-controller@3.0.0 
  │ │ │ │     │ │ └── event-target-shim@5.0.1 
  │ │ │ │     │ ├─┬ https-proxy-agent@2.2.1 
  │ │ │ │     │ │ └─┬ agent-base@4.2.1 
  │ │ │ │     │ │   └─┬ es6-promisify@5.0.0 
  │ │ │ │     │ │     └── es6-promise@4.2.6 
  │ │ │ │     │ └── node-fetch@2.3.0 
  │ │ │ │     ├─┬ google-p12-pem@1.0.4 
  │ │ │ │     │ └── node-forge@0.8.2 
  │ │ │ │     └── pify@4.0.1 
  │ │ │ ├── log-driver@1.2.7 
  │ │ │ ├── methmeth@1.1.0 
  │ │ │ ├── modelo@4.2.3 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ split-array-stream@1.0.3 
  │ │ │ │ └── is-stream-ended@0.1.4 
  │ │ │ └── string-format-obj@1.1.1 
  │ │ ├── arrify@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── compressible@2.0.16 
  │ │ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.6.2 
  │ │ │ ├── buffer-from@1.1.1 
  │ │ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6 
  │ │ ├─┬ create-error-class@3.0.2 
  │ │ │ └── capture-stack-trace@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ duplexify@3.7.1 
  │ │ │ └── stream-shift@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ gcs-resumable-upload@0.10.2 
  │ │ │ ├── configstore@3.1.2 
  │ │ │ └── google-auto-auth@0.10.1 
  │ │ ├── hash-stream-validation@0.2.1 
  │ │ ├── mime@2.4.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ pumpify@1.5.1 
  │ │ │ └── pump@2.0.1 
  │ │ ├── snakeize@0.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ stream-events@1.0.5 
  │ │ │ └── stubs@3.0.0 
  │ │ └── through2@2.0.5 
  │ ├── adm-zip@0.4.13 
  │ ├─┬ ajv@6.10.0 
  │ │ ├── fast-deep-equal@2.0.1 
  │ │ ├── fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├── json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 
  │ │ └─┬ uri-js@4.2.2 
  │ │   └── punycode@2.1.1 
  │ ├─┬ body-parser@1.18.3 
  │ │ ├── bytes@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── content-type@1.0.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.3 
  │ │ │ └── statuses@1.5.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ iconv-lite@0.4.23 
  │ │ │ └── safer-buffer@2.1.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.3.3 
  │ │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
  │ │ └─┬ type-is@1.6.16 
  │ │   └── media-typer@0.3.0 
  │ ├─┬ cli-table2@0.2.0 
  │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1 
  │ ├── colors@1.1.2 
  │ ├─┬ configstore@3.1.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ dot-prop@4.2.0 
  │ │ │ └── is-obj@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ make-dir@1.3.0 
  │ │ │ └── pify@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ unique-string@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── crypto-random-string@1.0.0 
  │ │ └─┬ write-file-atomic@2.4.2 
  │ │   └── signal-exit@3.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ express@4.16.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.5 
  │ │ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
  │ │ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
  │ │ ├── content-disposition@0.5.2 
  │ │ ├── cookie@0.3.1 
  │ │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
  │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
  │ │ ├── etag@1.8.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.1 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── statuses@1.4.0 
  │ │ ├── fresh@0.5.2 
  │ │ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── methods@1.1.2 
  │ │ ├── parseurl@1.3.2 
  │ │ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
  │ │ ├─┬ proxy-addr@2.0.4 
  │ │ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.2 
  │ │ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.8.0 
  │ │ ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ send@0.16.2 
  │ │ │ ├── debug@2.6.9 
  │ │ │ ├── mime@1.4.1 
  │ │ │ ├── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── statuses@1.4.0 
  │ │ ├── serve-static@1.13.2 
  │ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.0 
  │ │ ├── statuses@1.4.0 
  │ │ ├── utils-merge@1.0.1 
  │ │ └── vary@1.1.2 
  │ ├─┬ googleapis@23.0.2 
  │ │ ├── async@2.6.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ google-auth-library@0.12.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ gtoken@1.2.3 
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ google-p12-pem@0.1.2 
  │ │ │ │ │ └── node-forge@0.7.6 
  │ │ │ │ └── mime@1.6.0 
  │ │ │ └── lodash.merge@4.6.1 
  │ │ └── string-template@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ got@8.3.2 
  │ │ ├── @sindresorhus/is@0.7.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ cacheable-request@2.1.4 
  │ │ │ ├── clone-response@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├── http-cache-semantics@3.8.1 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ keyv@3.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ └── json-buffer@3.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├── lowercase-keys@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ normalize-url@2.0.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ query-string@5.1.1 
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── decode-uri-component@0.2.0 
  │ │ │ │ │ └── strict-uri-encode@1.1.0 
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ sort-keys@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ │   └── is-plain-obj@1.1.0 
  │ │ │ └── responselike@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── decompress-response@3.3.0 
  │ │ ├── duplexer3@0.1.4 
  │ │ ├── get-stream@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ into-stream@3.1.0 
  │ │ │ ├── from2@2.3.0 
  │ │ │ └── p-is-promise@1.1.0 
  │ │ ├── is-retry-allowed@1.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ isurl@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ has-to-string-tag-x@1.4.1 
  │ │ │ │ └── has-symbol-support-x@1.4.2 
  │ │ │ └── is-object@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── lowercase-keys@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── mimic-response@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── p-cancelable@0.4.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ p-timeout@2.0.1 
  │ │ │ └── p-finally@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── pify@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── timed-out@4.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ url-parse-lax@3.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── prepend-http@2.0.0 
  │ │ └── url-to-options@1.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ http-proxy@1.16.2 
  │ │ ├── eventemitter3@1.2.0 
  │ │ └── requires-port@1.0.0 
  │ ├── lodash@4.17.5 
  │ ├─┬ prompt@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── pkginfo@0.4.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ read@1.0.7 
  │ │ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.8 
  │ │ ├── revalidator@0.1.8 
  │ │ ├─┬ utile@0.3.0 
  │ │ │ ├── async@0.9.2 
  │ │ │ ├── deep-equal@0.2.2 
  │ │ │ ├── i@0.3.6 
  │ │ │ └── ncp@1.0.1 
  │ │ └─┬ winston@2.1.1 
  │ │   ├── async@1.0.0 
  │ │   ├── colors@1.0.3 
  │ │   └── pkginfo@0.3.1 
  │ ├── rimraf@2.6.2 
  │ ├── semver@5.5.0 
  │ ├─┬ serializerr@1.0.3 
  │ │ └── protochain@1.0.5 
  │ ├── uuid@3.2.1 
  │ ├─┬ winston@2.4.0 
  │ │ ├── async@1.0.0 
  │ │ └── colors@1.0.3 
  │ └─┬ yargs@11.0.0 
  │   ├─┬ cliui@4.1.0 
  │   │ ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
  │   │ │ └── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │   │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │   │ │ └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │   │ └── wrap-ansi@2.1.0 
  │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 
  │   ├─┬ find-up@2.1.0 
  │   │ └─┬ locate-path@2.0.0 
  │   │   ├─┬ p-locate@2.0.0 
  │   │   │ └─┬ p-limit@1.3.0 
  │   │   │   └── p-try@1.0.0 
  │   │   └── path-exists@3.0.0 
  │   ├── get-caller-file@1.0.3 
  │   ├─┬ os-locale@2.1.0 
  │   │ ├─┬ execa@0.7.0 
  │   │ │ ├── cross-spawn@5.1.0 
  │   │ │ ├── is-stream@1.1.0 
  │   │ │ ├── npm-run-path@2.0.2 
  │   │ │ └── strip-eof@1.0.0 
  │   │ ├─┬ lcid@1.0.0 
  │   │ │ └── invert-kv@1.0.0 
  │   │ └─┬ mem@1.1.0 
  │   │   └── mimic-fn@1.2.0 
  │   ├── require-directory@2.1.1 
  │   ├── require-main-filename@1.0.1 
  │   ├── set-blocking@2.0.0 
  │   ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
  │   │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │   │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │   │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │   ├── which-module@2.0.0 
  │   ├── y18n@3.2.1 
  │   └── yargs-parser@9.0.2 
  ├─┬ archiver@2.1.1 
  │ ├─┬ archiver-utils@1.3.0 
  │ │ ├── lazystream@1.0.0 
  │ │ └─┬ normalize-path@2.1.1 
  │ │   └── remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0 
  │ ├── async@2.6.2 
  │ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.13 
  │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.6 
  │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── process-nextick-args@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├── string_decoder@1.1.1 
  │ │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ tar-stream@1.6.2 
  │ │ ├── bl@1.2.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ buffer-alloc@1.2.0 
  │ │ │ ├── buffer-alloc-unsafe@1.1.0 
  │ │ │ └── buffer-fill@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── end-of-stream@1.4.1 
  │ │ ├── fs-constants@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── to-buffer@1.1.1 
  │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1 
  │ └─┬ zip-stream@1.2.0 
  │   └─┬ compress-commons@1.2.2 
  │     └─┬ crc32-stream@2.0.0 
  │       └─┬ crc@3.8.0 
  │         └─┬ buffer@5.2.1 
  │           ├── base64-js@1.3.0 
  │           └── ieee754@1.1.13 
  ├─┬ cjson@0.3.3 
  │ └─┬ json-parse-helpfulerror@1.0.3 
  │   └── jju@1.4.0 
  ├─┬ cli-color@1.4.0 
  │ ├── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
  │ ├── d@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ es5-ext@0.10.49 
  │ │ └── next-tick@1.0.0 
  │ ├── es6-iterator@2.0.3 
  │ ├─┬ memoizee@0.4.14 
  │ │ ├── es6-weak-map@2.0.2 
  │ │ ├── is-promise@2.1.0 
  │ │ └── lru-queue@0.1.0 
  │ └── timers-ext@0.1.7 
  ├─┬ cli-table@0.3.1 
  │ └── colors@1.0.3 
  ├── commander@2.20.0 
  ├─┬ configstore@1.4.0 
  │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.15 
  │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
  │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
  │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1 
  │ ├── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
  │ ├── osenv@0.1.5 
  │ ├── uuid@2.0.3 
  │ ├─┬ write-file-atomic@1.3.4 
  │ │ ├── imurmurhash@0.1.4 
  │ │ └── slide@1.1.6 
  │ └── xdg-basedir@2.0.0 
  ├─┬ cross-env@5.2.0 
  │ ├─┬ cross-spawn@6.0.5 
  │ │ ├── nice-try@1.0.5 
  │ │ ├── path-key@2.0.1 
  │ │ └─┬ shebang-command@1.2.0 
  │ │   └── shebang-regex@1.0.0 
  │ └── is-windows@1.0.2 
  ├─┬ cross-spawn@4.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ lru-cache@4.1.5 
  │ │ ├── pseudomap@1.0.2 
  │ │ └── yallist@2.1.2 
  │ └─┬ which@1.3.1 
  │   └── isexe@2.0.0 
  ├─┬ csv-streamify@3.0.4 
  │ └─┬ through2@2.0.1 
  │   └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6 
  │     ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
  │     └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  ├── didyoumean@1.2.1 
  ├─┬ es6-set@0.1.5 
  │ ├── es6-symbol@3.1.1 
  │ └── event-emitter@0.3.5 
  ├── exit-code@1.0.2 
  ├── filesize@3.6.1 
  ├─┬ firebase@2.4.2 
  │ └─┬ faye-websocket@0.9.3 
  │   └─┬ websocket-driver@0.5.2 
  │     └── websocket-extensions@0.1.1 
  ├─┬ fs-extra@0.23.1 
  │ ├── jsonfile@2.4.0 
  │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
  ├─┬ glob@7.1.3 
  │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6 
  │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 
  │ └── once@1.4.0 
  ├─┬ google-auto-auth@0.7.2 
  │ ├─┬ gcp-metadata@0.3.1 
  │ │ └── retry-request@3.3.2 
  │ └─┬ google-auth-library@0.10.0 
  │   ├─┬ gtoken@1.2.3 
  │   │ ├─┬ google-p12-pem@0.1.2 
  │   │ │ └── node-forge@0.7.6 
  │   │ └── mime@1.6.0 
  │   └── lodash.noop@3.0.1 
  ├─┬ inquirer@0.12.0 
  │ ├── ansi-escapes@1.4.0 
  │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
  │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
  │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
  │ │ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
  │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ cli-cursor@1.0.2 
  │ │ └─┬ restore-cursor@1.0.1 
  │ │   ├── exit-hook@1.1.1 
  │ │   └── onetime@1.1.0 
  │ ├── cli-width@2.2.0 
  │ ├── figures@1.7.0 
  │ ├─┬ readline2@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
  │ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.5 
  │ ├── run-async@0.1.0 
  │ ├── rx-lite@3.1.2 
  │ ├── string-width@1.0.2 
  │ └── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
  ├── is@3.3.0 
  ├── jsonschema@1.2.4 
  ├─┬ JSONStream@1.3.5 
  │ ├── jsonparse@1.3.1 
  │ └── through@2.3.8 
  ├─┬ jsonwebtoken@8.5.1 
  │ ├─┬ jws@3.2.2 
  │ │ └─┬ jwa@1.4.1 
  │ │   ├── buffer-equal-constant-time@1.0.1 
  │ │   └── ecdsa-sig-formatter@1.0.11 
  │ ├── lodash.includes@4.3.0 
  │ ├── lodash.isboolean@3.0.3 
  │ ├── lodash.isinteger@4.0.4 
  │ ├── lodash.isnumber@3.0.3 
  │ ├── lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6 
  │ ├── lodash.isstring@4.0.1 
  │ ├── lodash.once@4.1.1 
  │ └── ms@2.1.1 
  ├── lodash@4.17.11 
  ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4 
  │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.11 
  │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0 
  │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  ├─┬ opn@5.5.0 
  │ └── is-wsl@1.1.0 
  ├─┬ ora@0.2.3 
  │ └── cli-spinners@0.1.2 
  ├─┬ portfinder@1.0.20 
  │ ├── async@1.5.2 
  │ └─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │   └── ms@2.0.0 
  ├── progress@2.0.3 
  ├─┬ request@2.88.0 
  │ ├── aws-sign2@0.7.0 
  │ ├── aws4@1.8.0 
  │ ├── caseless@0.12.0 
  │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.7 
  │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
  │ ├── extend@3.0.2 
  │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
  │ ├─┬ form-data@2.3.3 
  │ │ └── asynckit@0.4.0 
  │ ├─┬ har-validator@5.1.3 
  │ │ └── har-schema@2.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.2.0 
  │ │ ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.4.1 
  │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.3.0 
  │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3 
  │ │ │ └── verror@1.10.0 
  │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.16.1 
  │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.4 
  │ │   ├── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2 
  │ │   ├── dashdash@1.14.1 
  │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.2 
  │ │   ├── getpass@0.1.7 
  │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.1 
  │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.5 
  │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
  │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
  │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.22 
  │ │ └── mime-db@1.38.0 
  │ ├── oauth-sign@0.9.0 
  │ ├── performance-now@2.1.0 
  │ ├── qs@6.5.2 
  │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2 
  │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.4.3 
  │ │ ├── psl@1.1.31 
  │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1 
  │ └── tunnel-agent@0.6.0 
  ├── semver@5.7.0 
  ├─┬ superstatic@6.0.4 
  │ ├── as-array@2.0.0 
  │ ├── async@1.5.2 
  │ ├── basic-auth-connect@1.0.0 
  │ ├── char-spinner@1.0.1 
  │ ├── compare-semver@1.1.0 
  │ ├─┬ compression@1.7.4 
  │ │ └─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │   └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ connect@3.6.6 
  │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ └─┬ finalhandler@1.1.0 
  │ │   └── statuses@1.3.1 
  │ ├─┬ connect-query@1.0.0 
  │ │ └── qs@6.4.0 
  │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
  │ ├─┬ fast-url-parser@1.1.3 
  │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1 
  │ ├─┬ fs-extra@0.30.0 
  │ │ └── klaw@1.3.1 
  │ ├─┬ glob-slasher@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── glob-slash@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ lodash.isobject@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ └── lodash._objecttypes@2.4.1 
  │ │ └── toxic@1.0.1 
  │ ├── home-dir@1.0.0 
  │ ├── is-url@1.2.4 
  │ ├─┬ join-path@1.1.1 
  │ │ ├── url-join@0.0.1 
  │ │ └── valid-url@1.0.9 
  │ ├─┬ morgan@1.9.1 
  │ │ ├── basic-auth@2.0.1 
  │ │ └─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │   └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ nash@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── async@1.5.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ flat-arguments@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ as-array@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ ├── lodash.isarguments@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├── lodash.isobject@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ lodash.values@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ │   └─┬ lodash.keys@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ │     ├── lodash._isnative@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ │     └── lodash._shimkeys@2.4.1 
  │ │ │ ├── lodash.isarguments@3.1.0 
  │ │ │ └── lodash.isobject@3.0.2 
  │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0 
  │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
  │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
  │ ├── on-headers@1.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ path-to-regexp@1.7.0 
  │ │ └── isarray@0.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ router@1.3.3 
  │ │ ├── array-flatten@2.1.1 
  │ │ └─┬ debug@2.6.9 
  │ │   └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ ├── rsvp@3.6.2 
  │ ├── string-length@1.0.1 
  │ └── try-require@1.2.1 
  ├─┬ tar@4.4.8 
  │ ├── chownr@1.1.1 
  │ ├── fs-minipass@1.2.5 
  │ ├─┬ minipass@2.3.5 
  │ │ └── yallist@3.0.3 
  │ ├── minizlib@1.2.1 
  │ └── yallist@3.0.3 
  ├── tmp@0.0.33 
  ├─┬ universal-analytics@0.4.20 
  │ └── debug@3.2.6 
  ├─┬ update-notifier@2.5.0 
  │ ├─┬ boxen@1.3.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ ansi-align@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
  │ │ │   ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │ │ │   └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │ │ │     └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── camelcase@4.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ chalk@2.4.2 
  │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@3.2.1 
  │ │ │ └── supports-color@5.5.0 
  │ │ ├── cli-boxes@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
  │ │ │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │ │ │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── term-size@1.2.0 
  │ │ └─┬ widest-line@2.0.1 
  │ │   └─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
  │ │     ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │ │     └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │ │       └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ chalk@2.4.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@3.2.1 
  │ │ │ └─┬ color-convert@1.9.3 
  │ │ │   └── color-name@1.1.3 
  │ │ └─┬ supports-color@5.5.0 
  │ │   └── has-flag@3.0.0 
  │ ├── configstore@3.1.2 
  │ ├── import-lazy@2.1.0 
  │ ├─┬ is-ci@1.2.1 
  │ │ └── ci-info@1.6.0 
  │ ├─┬ is-installed-globally@0.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ global-dirs@0.1.1 
  │ │ │ └── ini@1.3.5 
  │ │ └─┬ is-path-inside@1.0.1 
  │ │   └── path-is-inside@1.0.2 
  │ ├── is-npm@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ latest-version@3.1.0 
  │ │ └─┬ package-json@4.0.1 
  │ │   ├─┬ got@6.7.1 
  │ │   │ ├── is-redirect@1.0.0 
  │ │   │ ├── unzip-response@2.0.1 
  │ │   │ └─┬ url-parse-lax@1.0.0 
  │ │   │   └── prepend-http@1.0.4 
  │ │   ├─┬ registry-auth-token@3.4.0 
  │ │   │ └─┬ rc@1.2.8 
  │ │   │   ├── deep-extend@0.6.0 
  │ │   │   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
  │ │   │   └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1 
  │ │   └── registry-url@3.1.0 
  │ ├── semver-diff@2.1.0 
  │ └── xdg-basedir@3.0.0 
  ├─┬ user-home@2.0.0 
  │ └── os-homedir@1.0.2 
  ├── uuid@3.3.2 
  └─┬ winston@1.1.2 
    ├── async@1.0.0 
    ├── colors@1.0.3 
    ├── cycle@1.0.3 
    ├── eyes@0.1.8 
    ├── pkginfo@0.3.1 
    └── stack-trace@0.0.10
```

Might be success in install! BUT
Issue is When I'm trying to run **"firebase login"** any other "firebase" command that It give me error like

> -bash: firebase: command not found

Any setup I required? Guide me.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with Flutter.

Comment: @iPatel, you might have already solved this but I think I remember having an issue with this too. Check where you installed firebase in your project folder. the issue might lie there.